# How make sure that a Composite also lays out its children after calling Composite.layout() in Java

Tags: java, layout, composite

I'm having a Composite with children, which are possibly composites too but can also be other Controls.
For Example like this

```
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
Composite childrenComposite = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
Control childrenChildrenControl = new Control(childrenComposite, SWT.NONE);
Control childrenControl = new Control(composite, SWT.NONE);
```

And if i call `composite.layout()` i want that childrenComposite also calls it layout-Method.
Is this done automatically?
Or do i have to call it separately?

```
composite.layout();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the following.
If u want to make sure that all childrens of a Composite also get layouted use

```
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
Composite childrenComposite = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
Control childrenChildrenControl = new Control(childrenComposite, SWT.NONE);
Control childrenControl = new Control(composite, SWT.NONE);

composite.layout(true, true);
```